# <fragment> tag equivalent in anko DSL

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

How can I replace this XML with Anko DSL equivalent?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

      // more code here....

      <fragment android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
          android:layout_width="340dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          android:name="com.myapp.MyFragment"
          />

      // more code here....

</LinearLayout>
```

Anko version:

```
UI {
    linearLayout {
        orientation= VERTICAL

        fragment {  // error! 
             name = "com.myapp.MyFragment"
        }

    }.lparams(width=..., height=...)
}
```

Seems there is no eqiuvalen for fragment tag in DSL.

Thanks!

Comment: `// error!`. What error?

Comment: Error is that there is no such thing as "fragment" in anko. The question is how to convert provided XML view into anko DSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no special function in Anko, you can just use Android APIs for doing this.

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(this.id,
        com.myapp.MyFragment()).commit()
```

Note that you need to set an `id` to your `linearLayout`, as `add` method requires it being set.

Comment: Thank you, yanex!
And can you tell me, do you have forum or user group specially for Anko or SO is the best place to post Anko related questions?

Comment: For now you can just use 'Android' category for such kind of posts. And, also, we have Slack community with the #anko channel.